Resize 200 photos quickly in C++ using opencv
I have about 200 photos that I need to up load to a WordPress website. When I tried up loading the second one I got an error message that the file was too wide. Apparently WordPress limits the width of the photo uploads to 2560 columns (pixels?).
I converted 32 by hand and then got tired of all the manual labor.
This program is a test of the class I created to resize and rename all the pictures in the directory. The 17 pictures I chose to test it all change to the size specified and the resized pictures are stored in the proper directory and properly named.
The code uses the opencv library to resize the images. This is my first use of the opencv library.
The code uses std::filesystem rather than string manipulation to rename the files.
What other features of C++, especially C++23 can I use to decrease the amount of code in PhotoResizer.cpp?
Am I using the most modern features of C++ available to accomplish my goal?
What can be done better?
Development Environment

GCC 12
C++ 23
Ubuntu 22.04
opencv 4.10

Directory listing of the source directory and the target director.

PhotoResizer.h
#ifndef PHOTORESIZER_H
#define PHOTORESIZER_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

/*
 * Assumptions:
 *   The current working directory contains the JPEG files.
 *   File names in list passed in will have been processed to remove directory
 */

class PhotoResizer
{
public:
    PhotoResizer(std::string targDir, std::string postFix,std::vector<std::string> resizelist, bool fixFName = true, std::size_t maxwidth = 0);
    ~PhotoResizer() = default;
    std::size_t resizeAllInList();

private:
    const std::size_t WordPressMaxPhotoWidth = 2560;
    bool resizeAndSavePhoto(std::string imageName);
    std::string targetDirectory;
    std::string resizedPostfix;
    std::vector<std::string> photoList;
    bool fixFileName;
    std::size_t maxWdith = WordPressMaxPhotoWidth;
    std::size_t maxHeight = WordPressMaxPhotoWidth;

};

#endif

PhotoResizer.cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <filesystem>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "PhotoResizer.h"
#include <ranges>

PhotoResizer::PhotoResizer(
    std::string targDir,
    std::string postFix,
    std::vector<std::string> resizelist,
    bool fixFName,
    std::size_t maxwidth
)
: targetDirectory{targDir},
resizedPostfix{postFix},
photoList{resizelist},
fixFileName{fixFName}
{
    if (maxwidth > 0)
    {
        maxWdith = maxwidth;
    }
}

std::size_t PhotoResizer::resizeAllInList()
{
    std::size_t resizedCount = 0;

    for (auto picture: photoList)
    {
        if (resizeAndSavePhoto(picture))
        {
            ++resizedCount;
        }
    }

    return resizedCount;
}

/*
 * The static functions prevent the propagation of opencv2/opencv.hpp and
 * filesystem to the entire program
 */
static cv::Mat resizePhoto(std::string imageName, std::size_t maxWdith)
{
    cv::Mat resizedImage;

    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(imageName);

    if (image.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Could not read image " << imageName << "!\n";
        return image;
    }

    if (static_cast<std::size_t>(image.cols)  > maxWdith)
    {
        double ratio = static_cast<double>(maxWdith) / static_cast<double>(image.cols);
        std::size_t newHeight = static_cast<int>(image.rows * ratio);

        cv::Size newSize(maxWdith, newHeight);

        cv::resize(image, resizedImage, newSize);

        // Display the resized image
        cv::imshow("Resized Image", resizedImage);
        cv::waitKey(0);
    }

    return resizedImage;
}

static std::string renamePhotoFile(std::string imageName, bool fixFileName, std::string postFix)
{
    std::string noPathOrExtension = std::filesystem::path(imageName).stem();
    std::string extension = std::filesystem::path(imageName).extension();
    std::string webSafeName;

    // Create a web safe file name, replace any non alpha numeric characers with underscore
    if (fixFileName)
    {
        auto op = [](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char { return std::isalnum(c)? c : '_'; };
        std::ranges::transform(noPathOrExtension, std::back_inserter(webSafeName), op);
    }
    else
    {
        webSafeName = noPathOrExtension;
    }

    if (!postFix.empty())
    {
        webSafeName += "." + postFix;
    }

    webSafeName += extension;

    return webSafeName;
}

static bool renameAndSave(cv::Mat resizedPhoto, std::string imageName, bool fixFileName, std::string postFix, std::string targetDirectory)
{
    std::string webSafeName = renamePhotoFile(imageName, fixFileName, postFix);

    if (!targetDirectory.empty())
    {
        webSafeName = targetDirectory + "/" + webSafeName; 
    }
    bool saved = cv::imwrite(webSafeName, resizedPhoto);

    if (!saved) {
        std::cerr << "Could not write image " << imageName << " to file!\n";
    }

    return saved;
}

bool PhotoResizer::resizeAndSavePhoto(std::string imageName)
{
    cv::Mat resized = resizePhoto(imageName, maxWdith);
    

    if (resized.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Could not read image " << imageName << "!\n";
        return false;
    }

    return renameAndSave(resized, imageName, fixFileName, resizedPostfix, targetDirectory);
}


main.cpp
include <iostream>
#include "PhotoResizer.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> photosPaths =
    {
        "TestImages/BHHS Class of 74 50th Reunion Prints (32).jpg",
        "TestImages/BHHS Class of 74 50th Reunion Prints (38).jpg",
        "TestImages/BHHS Class of 74 50th Reunion Prints (44).jpg",
        "TestImages/BHHS Class of 74 50th Reunion Prints (33).jpg",
        "TestImages/BHHS Class of 74 50th Reunion Prints (39).jpg",
        "TestImages/BHHS Class of 74 50th Reunion Prints (45).jpg",
        "TestImages/BHHS Class of 74 50th Reunion Prints (34).jpg",
        "TestImages/BHHS Class of 74 50th Reunion Prints (40).jpg",
        "TestImages/BHHS Class of 74 50th Reunion Prints (46).jpg",
        "TestImages/BHHS Class of 74 50th Reunion Prints (35).jpg",
        "TestImages/BHHS Class of 74 50th Reunion Prints (41).jpg",
        "TestImages/BHHS Class of 74 50th Reunion Prints (47).jpg",
        "TestImages/BHHS Class of 74 50th Reunion Prints (36).jpg",
        "TestImages/BHHS Class of 74 50th Reunion Prints (42).jpg",
        "TestImages/BHHS Class of 74 50th Reunion Prints (48).jpg",
        "TestImages/BHHS Class of 74 50th Reunion Prints (37).jpg",
        "TestImages/BHHS Class of 74 50th Reunion Prints (43).jpg", 
        "TestImages/image.jpg"
    };

    PhotoResizer myresizer("testOut", "resized", photosPaths, true, 1200);

    if (myresizer.resizeAllInList() != photosPaths.size())
    {
        std::cerr << "Not all files resized ";
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}



It’s actually refreshing to see a code review request for a C++ project that does something useful, rather than abstract stuff or coding challenge nonsense.

Thanks for sharing some nice C++ code.
There's a lot of code in there, and experience teaches us that
if there's a bunch of source lines there's probably a bunch of bugs
lurking in there, as well.
If the goal is "let's learn the OpenCV library!" or otherwise do some
reinventing of wheels, then great, this is an ideal project for that.
But my understanding of the project's motivation is that
a real world WordPress-related need was driving it.
The OP makes it clear that we have devoted significant
engineering resource to it.
Good engineers are lazy.
Very lazy.
Designing, implementing, documenting, testing, and maintaining quality code
is hard. It's a lot of effort, it's time consuming.
Sometimes we'll find that our particular itch has already been scratched,
or at least there is code that does close to what we want.
And then we examine that code's features,
like cost to acquire versus cost to roll our own codebase,
ease of learning to use it, performance, portability, and other constraints.
Becoming familiar with useful tools clearly is valuable.
OpenCV is a great example, being free, performant, portable to diverse OS's,
and offering bindings for lots of languages.
Once you know the library, it's straightforward to leverage
that on embedded Raspberry Pi or a Windows desktop or other environments.
The GraphicsMagick
library and
command line tools
are similarly versatile, and worth knowing about.
nit, typo: maxWdith
core resizing functionality
The core routine does some error checking / reporting
in the course of resizing an image, and caller does some as well.
Consider using the gm utility, which already handles such details.
It is well documented.
I personally found it a little surprising that "max width" is
actually a constant "output width", even for a tiny icon input file.
Apparently we're using the default
interpolation
approach in that situation.
Consider addressing the core need with a one-liner bash script:
gm convert "$1" -resize '2560x1920>' "resized/$1"

If you want to support resize.sh some/long/path/image1.jpg you might use:
INFILE="${1:-supply_an_input_image_path.jpg}"
OUTFILE="resized/$(basename "$INFILE")"
gm convert "$INFILE" -resize '2560x1920>' "$OUTFILE"

The -geometry section of the man page explains

Use > to change the dimensions of the image only if its width or height exceeds the geometry specification.

This minimalist "tools approach" leaves inspecting output images
as a separate step, and supports batch updates (with a for loop)
without need of repeating a keystroke for each processed image.
doing just one thing
At a high level we're changing filename so it's web-safe,
and changing the pixels.
That first task sounds like it needs less interactive supervision.
Consider breaking out two separate commands,
one for batch renames and another for interactive image viewing.

Almost every project I work on requires some learning, which is what makes being a software engineer exciting for me. This is a "I want to learn opencv" project. Before I started I thought it would be a learn opengl project, I discovered it was opencv instead. I've learned C++, C#, .Net, object oriented programming, Drupal, Wordpress, PHP, jQuery, Perl and embedded programing on the job. Unfortunately I've forgotten most of the Perl

@pacmaninbw Excellent! That's the aspect I was looking for and not finding in the OP's motivating paragraph plus the lack of a reinventing-the-wheel tag, as hashed out in the (now deleted) comments. Knowing there's an off the shelf solution available and choosing to roll your own anyway is perfectly legitimate, it is the hacker's way. Learning new tools is a journey on a long path -- keep going down it!

class PhotoResizer

auto thing_doer = ThingDoer{a, b, c}; thing_doer.do_thing() is an anti-pattern. There is absolutely no benefit over just do_thing(a, b, c). And in fact, there are multiple hidden costs.
It seems to me that it makes more sense to have a resize_image() function, that (basically) just takes a source path, a destination path, and a width, which is plenty reusable in its own right. Then you could also have a resize_images() function that takes a list of images, a destination path, and a width, that handles calling resize_image() on multiple images (with some extra power, which I’ll get to later).
    PhotoResizer(std::string targDir, std::string postFix,std::vector<std::string> resizelist, bool fixFName = true, std::size_t maxwidth = 0);

I am not a fan of default arguments in general, but this use seems particularly egregious. Literally the entire point of this class is to resize images to a given max width. It seems unwise to hide perhaps the most important parameter. It seems even unwise-er to default it to zero.
If anything, the fixName parameter seems to be the optional one, and that should be defaulted at the end (though naked bool parameters are also an anti-pattern). If you really want to let maxwidth have a default, that’s fine, but it should probably come before fixName.
But even better: pull the fixName functionality out of this class completely. It doesn’t need to be there, and it shouldn’t be there. An image resizer does not need to know how to condition filenames.
What you should probably have is a completely separate utility that takes a list of “input” file names, and produces a list of “output” file names, using whatever logic you please. Then you just pass the list of to→from filename pairs to the image resizer function.
And that utility should probably also be doing more than just blindly post-fixing stuff onto input filenames, and putting everything into a single directory, because there are a lot of ways that can go wrong. You should probably have some logic to check for duplicates, filesystem links leading to suspicious aliasing, any overlap between the input and output paths, and potentially destructive overwriting, among other things, lest a command-line typo wipe out an entire directory tree of precious photos.
Anywho, back to the constructor. targDir is a path to a directory, so it should be a std::filesystem::path. The same is true for the input paths. And there is no need to take the list of input paths as a vector. (And certainly no need to copy that vector, except for the fact that you’re using the ThingDoer anti-pattern.)
    ~PhotoResizer() = default;

There is no need for this. It’s just noise.
PhotoResizer::PhotoResizer(
    std::string targDir,
    std::string postFix,
    std::vector<std::string> resizelist,
    bool fixFName,
    std::size_t maxwidth
)
: targetDirectory{targDir},
resizedPostfix{postFix},
photoList{resizelist},
fixFileName{fixFName}
{
    if (maxwidth > 0)
    {
        maxWdith = maxwidth;
    }
}

I mean, if you must use the ThingDoer anti-pattern and hold copies of all the arguments, you could at least move them to get back some of the efficiency you’ve lost.
/*
 * The static functions prevent the propagation of opencv2/opencv.hpp and
 * filesystem to the entire program
 */

What does this mean?
static cv::Mat resizePhoto(std::string imageName, std::size_t maxWdith)
{
    cv::Mat resizedImage;

Declaring variables at the top of functions is obsolete even in C. In this case, you don’t even know if you’ll need this variable yet.
Also, you should probably be taking the string by const& at least, if not as a std::string_view. (Though in this case, you’re kinda stymied by the fact that OpenCV doesn’t work with string views, so you’d need to reconstruct a string anyway.)
static cv::Mat resizePhoto(std::string imageName, std::size_t maxWdith)
{
    cv::Mat resizedImage;

    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(imageName);

    if (image.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Could not read image " << imageName << "!\n";
        return image;
    }

So here’s a good spot to include some C++23. You mentioned that at some point you might want to wrap this in GUI. Well, when you do that, reporting errors via std::cerr just isn’t going to work.
You should look into std::expected. Now, I don’t think the community has settled on exactly how to use std::expected yet—like, should you use an error enumeration, or should you use std::exception_ptr, or a variant of error types—so this advice might not age well, but I’d suggest an error enumeration. You’ll need to think up every possible error your resize functions might encounter, and encode them in an error enumeration:
enum class photo_resize_errc
{
    no_error,
    image_read_error,
    // ... etc.
};

You could also make this a proper <system_error> error enumeration if you want, but that’s not necessary for std::expected.
Then you just wrap your function return type in std::expected, with your error enumeration, and you’re golden:
auto resizePhoto(std::string const& imageName, std::size_t maxWdith)
    -> std::expected<cv::Mat, photo_resize_errc>
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(imageName);

    if (image.empty())
        return std::unexpected{photo_resize_errc::image_read_error};

std::expected is viral, so once you start using it, you will probably find you have to propagate it throughout your API. For example:
auto PhotoResizer::resizeAndSavePhoto(std::string const& imageName)
    // Don't actually need the bool value - it was just an error flag - so we can properly return void.
    -> std::expected<void, photo_resize_errc>
{

    return resizePhoto(imageName, maxWdith)
        .and_then([this](cv::Mat resized) {
            return renameAndSave(resized, imageName, fixFileName, resizedPostfix, targetDirectory);
        });
}

But back to resizePhoto(). So you return an empty cv::Mat to signal an error… but you also return an empty cv::Mat if resizing is not necessary. Is that on purpose?
        std::size_t newHeight = static_cast<int>(image.rows * ratio);

Why cast to int then put it in a std::size_t instead of just directly casting to std::size_t?
static std::string renamePhotoFile(std::string imageName, bool fixFileName, std::string postFix)
{
    std::string noPathOrExtension = std::filesystem::path(imageName).stem();
    std::string extension = std::filesystem::path(imageName).extension();
    std::string webSafeName;

    // Create a web safe file name, replace any non alpha numeric characers with underscore
    if (fixFileName)
    {
        auto op = [](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char { return std::isalnum(c)? c : '_'; };
        std::ranges::transform(noPathOrExtension, std::back_inserter(webSafeName), op);
    }
    else
    {
        webSafeName = noPathOrExtension;
    }

    if (!postFix.empty())
    {
        webSafeName += "." + postFix;
    }

    webSafeName += extension;

    return webSafeName;
}

I think you may have some issues here, but since I don’t work with non-POSIX platforms, I’m not sure.
Firstly, I don’t think it’s guaranteed that paths can be converted to std::strings. In fact, I think on Windows, that won’t work, because Windows paths use wide characters. Generally converting paths to strings and back is fraught, because there may be encoding issues.
I also don’t think it’s necessarily guaranteed that path.stem() + path.extension() == path.filename(), so you may not necessarily end up with the filename you expect.
But it’s going to be generally true that any path manipulation will be non-portable. So I guess you’ll just have to live with that.
Now, from the start, since imageName is supposed to be a path, you should probably take it as a path. Then when you extract the stem and extension, you can avoid the unnecessary duplication.
Now when you “fix” the stem (note: you don’t fix the extension! if you really want web-safe file names, watch out!), you make a copy… but that’s not necessary. Consider:
auto renamePhotoFile(std::filesystem::path const& imageName, bool fixFileName, std::string postFix)
    // Note: return a path, not a string... because it's a path, not just a string. Also, see the final return statement.
    -> std::filesystem::path
{
    auto const is_non_alnum = [](char c) { return not std::isalnum(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)); };

    // If we don't need to touch the filename... don't.
    if (not fixFileName and postFix.empty())
        return imageName.filename();

    // Should probably check  that imageName.has_filename() is true, and that
    // imageName.filename().generic_string() is not '.' or '..'.

    auto stem = imageName.stem().generic_string();
    auto extension = imageName.extension().generic_string();

    // Should probably check to make sure stem is not '.' or '..', and
    // that imageName.has_filename() is true.

    if (fixFileName)
    {
        std::ranges::replace_if(stem, is_non_alnum, '_');

        // Maybe also make sure the extension is fixed?
    }

    if (not postFix.empty())
    {
        stem.reserve(stem.size() + 1 + postFix.size());
        stem += '.';
        stem += postFix;
    }

    // Note that we don't just return the string; we convert it to a path.
    //
    // Note also that we are careful to specify the *generic* path format.
    // Why? Because things can go really wacky with non-generic paths.
    // With generic paths, we know for damn sure that anything that doesn't
    // have '/' in it is a single path component. But other systems might use
    // something else as the path separator (like, OpenVMS uses '.'), so
    // something like 'x.y' *might* be a file name... or it might be a
    // path to file 'y' in directory 'x'... or *anything else*.
    //
    // So we convert to a path, and we do so using the generic format
    // specifically, to avoid nasty surprises elsewhere.
    return std::filesystem::path{stem + extension, std::filesystem::path::format::generic_format};
}

And of course the function should probably return a std::expected<std::filesystem::path, ...>, because it can fail.
static bool renameAndSave(cv::Mat resizedPhoto, std::string imageName, bool fixFileName, std::string postFix, std::string targetDirectory)
{
    std::string webSafeName = renamePhotoFile(imageName, fixFileName, postFix);

    if (!targetDirectory.empty())
    {
        webSafeName = targetDirectory + "/" + webSafeName; 
    }
    bool saved = cv::imwrite(webSafeName, resizedPhoto);

    if (!saved) {
        std::cerr << "Could not write image " << imageName << " to file!\n";
    }

    return saved;
}

So let’s apply std::expected and the filesystem path stuff from before to this function. We might get something like this:
auto renameAndSave(cv::Mat resizedPhoto, std::filesystem::path const& imageName, bool fixFileName, std::string const& postFix, std::filesystem::path const& targetDirectory)
    -> std::expected<void, photo_resize_errc>
{
    return renamePhotoFile(imageName, fixFileName, postFix)
        .and_then([&targetDirectory](auto&& filename)
        {
            return targetDirectory / filename;
        })
        .and_then([&resizedPhoto](auto&& path)
        {
            if (not cv::imwrite(path.string(), resizedPhoto))
                return std::unexpected{photo_resize_errc::could_not_write_image};
            return {};
        })
    ;
}


If your primary interest is reducing the amount of code, ditching the class and using just functions will probably eliminate somewhere between 1⁄3 to 2⁄3 of the code.
However, I find the other question more interesting: how to use modern features to improve the code.
I’ve already mentioned std::expected extensively. That would make your error handling much simpler, and more flexible, especially if your long-term goal is supporting both TUI and GUI error output (though, unfortunately, it’s all much more verbose than using exceptions).
Unfortunately, the real monster that would give you incredible power isn’t yet available as of C++23. What this code could really benefit from is std::execution, which is currently on track for C++26. We don’t have that yet, but we can plan ahead and design the code so that when it does become available, it will easy to refactor to it.
Naturally, someone’s already pointed out in the comments that you could do this with a shell script and ImageMagick. But there are ways we can vastly improve on that. And one of the keys to really beating the “simple” solution is to leverage concurrency.
Consider that there are no✱ inter-dependencies between any two images that you are resizing. In other words, there is no reason you could not be resizing one or more images concurrently.
✱ (“No” is doing a lot of work here. Let’s assume that in the list of images, there are no duplicates (possibly disguised by links or aliases). Let’s also assume that none of the input images are already in the output directory, directly or indirectly. Let’s also assume that each input image gets mapped to a distinct output path (in other words dir1/img.jpg and dir2/img.jpg somehow get mapped to different output files). This is all stuff you should probably check before starting the resizing (or as-you-go, but carefully).)
Let’s start with the assumption that we have a function that takes the path to an image, resizes it if necessary, and writes the result to an output path:
auto resize_image(std::filesystem::path src, int max_width, std::filesystem::path out);

(We take everything by value because, with concurrent work, we’re going to need to copy/move everything anyway, because we will be returning from the function before we’re done using the function arguments.)
Now, in the future execution library, what we’d want to do to make this function concurrent is take a scheduler parameter that defines where it should do its work, and return a sender that completes when the work is done:
auto resize_image(std::execution::scheduler auto sch, std::filesystem::path src, int max_width, std::filesystem::path out) -> std::execution::sender auto;

Since we don’t have schedules or senders yet, we’ll have to fall back on old-school futures, and roll our own half-assed supporting infrastructure.
Let’s start with a half-assed “scheduler” for resize tasks, which is really not a scheduler at all, but rather a task manager for resize tasks on a thread pool:
class half_assed_fake_scheduler
{
    std::vector<std::jthread> _threads;
    std::vector<std::tuple<std::filesystem::path, std::filesystem::path, int, std::promise<void>>> _tasks;
    std::vector<std::future<void>> _futures;
    std::atomic<std::size_t> _current_task;
    std::atomic_flag _running;

    static auto _thread_func(std::stop_token stop_token, half_assed_fake_scheduler& sch) -> void
    {
        sch._running.wait(false);

        while (not stop_token.stop_requested())
        {
            auto task_num = _current_task++;
            if (task_num >= _tasks.size())
                break;

            // Do image resize. When done, call `promise.set_value()`.
            // If error, do `promise.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(std::runtime_error{...}))`.
        }
    }

public:
    half_assed_fake_scheduler()
        : _threads(std::ranges::max(std::jthread::hardware_concurrency(), 1u))
    {
        std::ranges::for_each(_threads, [this](auto&& t) { t = std::jthread{_thread_func, this}; });
    }

    ~half_assed_fake_scheduler()
    {
        std::ranges::for_each(_threads, &std::jthread::request_stop);

        _running.test_and_set();
        _running.notify_all();
    }

    auto schedule(std::filesystem::path src, std::filesystem::path out, int max_width)
    {
        _tasks.reserve(_tasks.size() + 1);
        _futures.reserve(_futures.size() + 1);

        _tasks.emplace_back(std::move(src), std::move(out), max_width);
        _futures.emplace_back(_tasks.back().promise.get_future());
    }

    // Can only call this once!
    //
    // And only *after* all scheduling is done.
    auto sync_wait()
    {
        _running.test_and_set();
        _running.notify_all();

        return std::move(_futures);
    }
};

Now we do:
auto resize_image(half_assed_fake_scheduler& sch, std::filesystem::path src, int max_width, std::filesystem::path out) -> std::future<void>;

And the implementation is just:
auto resize_image(half_assed_fake_scheduler& sch, std::filesystem::path src, int max_width, std::filesystem::path out) -> std::future<void>
{
    return sch.schedule(std::move(src), std::move(out), max_width);
}

All of this is in a wrapper function:
template<std::ranges::input_range R>
requires std::convertible_to<std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>, std::filesystem::path>
auto resize_images(R&& images, int max_width)
{
    auto sch = half_assed_fake_scheduler{}

    std::ranges::for_each(std::forward<R>(images),
        [&sch, max_width](auto&& src)
        {
            auto out = /* generate output path somehow */;

            sch.schedule(std::forward<decltype(src)>(src), std::move(out), max_width);
        });

    auto futures = sch.sync_wait();

    // Now all the images are being resized concurrently.

    // Wait for success, or report failures.
    std::ranges::for_each(futures,
        [](auto&& future)
        {
            try
            {
                future.get();
            }
            catch (std::exception const& x)
            {
                std::cerr << x.what() << '\n';
            }
        });
}

That’s a very rough outline, but hopefully it will get you started. In a real program, GUI or otherwise, you would provide your own scheduler—possibly just a thread pool—then schedule all the resize operations, then start them off, then monitor them for the results (or cancel them early if you like). With a GUI, you would probably display a “in progress” light then switch it to “done” or “failed” depending on the result for each image. A command line program would probably just display “src filename resized to out filename” for successes, and “failed to resize src filename: (reason)” for failures. Hopefully it’s clear enough from the above how to do so.
Honestly, I would wait for the final rubber stamp on std::execution before getting too deep into the planning, especially because I don’t know how well std::future is going to be integrated with senders. There are already prototype std::execution libraries, so as soon as the design is finalized, you will already have implementations you can begin testing with even before there are actual standard library implementations.
But, definitely do consider adding concurrency as the next step. For something like this, you could be looking at massive gains.

Note that cv::resize() is already multi-threaded itself, so using a thread pool is probably counter-productive.

I am aware OpenCV already uses concurrency internally, but you will almost certainly still see gains if you are resizing multiple images at once. Even just reading the data from disk can be done more concurrently.

Where does one learn anti-patterns versus patterns.

Books, blogs, videos. Scott Meyers’s books used to be the premier resource, but they are very, very dated now. I think the best current starting resource is the Core Guidelines, but take your time reading through them. For blogs, Bartlomiej Filipek and Sandor Dargo both publish topically and frequently. If you prefer videos, Jason Turner is the man.
